# how do I fix overflow on tub?

Tags: plumbing, drain, replacement

Tub at new place looks as such.

[image: drain1]
[image: drain2]

I want to find a cover for overflow drain but I'm having a hard time.

Bought this cover kit: https://www.homedepot.com/p/DANCO-Lift-and-Turn-Bath-Tub-Drain-Trim-Kit-with-Overflow-in-Oil-Rubbed-Bronze-89487/202251686, but it seems way off.

Do I need to remove the threaded part first? Does it screw out? Don't want to damage anything.

Comment: You want a cover with internal(female) threads not external(male).  I would return it and try to find something similar, but with the threads inside.

Comment: I have Googled looking for a cover with threads on the inside, I'm not sure they exist.

Comment: It does look a bit weird with the locking ring(black) on it.  Is there an access panel on the wall behind it so you could fix the plumbing?  If worst comes, find a cover that will fit(tight fix) inside the pipe and use silicon caulking to seal it on.

Comment: After a lot of Googling I found a Watco Innovator Overflow Plate 18009. If this doesn't do it I think I have to call the plumber. No access panel unfortunately.

Comment: I am flagging to close as a product recommendation.

Comment: Should I remove product name?

Answer (score 2):

That overflow is obviously missing a cover, but they're not normally like that to begin with:

[image][image]

I think someone lost the part and DIY some pipe in there.

Answer (score 0):

You could get one of these cute little guys to put over it:
https://www.walmart.com/ip/XINQITE-Bathtub-Overflow-Drainage-Cover-Tub-Cover-Soak-Bath-Bathroom-Spa-Accessories-Adds-Inches-Of-Water-For-Height/1730435985/